# Is it possible to capture and export a running process over ssh with x?

Tags: ssh, terminal, xorg, x-server

I've seen plenty of questions on the web about exporting a display from a remote host to a local.  I can get this to work fine, but that's only for commands run after logging into that terminal.  Is it possible to export a currently running process/it's window over ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can run only "new" commands from remote shell that will use your display (X server). It can't be also used for running full featured graphical session, nor to view whole "Desktop" like VNC and it was never intended to.

Comment: Thanks.  So VNC would be the way to go for this? As in, vnc is capable of capturing a running window?

Comment: If you want to connect to existing session on remote host and run full featured *DE, yes VNC is probably the most universal tool to do so.

Comment: I don't think my remote host is using *DE, I believe it is MWM, but hopefully that isn't an issue.